# Using 'replace' with a regex is throwing an error. Any ideas why?

Tags: regex, wysiwyg

I am attempting to strip out `<p>` tags around `<img>` tags that are automatically getting generated in a WYSIWYG field.

**The error:** preg_replace(): `Unknown modifier '&gt;'`

```
{{ story.html|raw|replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU','\1\2\3') }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on with the `story.html` part, but you'll need to double escape your regex.

Assuming you have an entry already with a `story` Rich Text field, it'd look like this:

```
{{ entry.body|raw|replace("/<p>\\s*(<a .*>)?\\s*(<img .* \\/>)\\s*(<\\/a>)?\\s*<\\/p>/iU", "\1\2\3") }}
```